# How to add a docker health check to test a tcp port is open?

Tags: docker

I have a server which is running an apache hive service on port 9083. The thing is it doesn't support `http` protocol (but uses `thrift` protocol).so I can't simply add

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD http://127.0.0.1:9083 || exit 1 #  this check fails
```

All I want is to check if that port is open. I have `netstat` and `curl` on server but not `nc`.

So far I tried the below options, but none of them is suitable as a health check.

```
netstat -an | grep 9083 | grep LISTEN | echo $?  # This works
netstat -an | grep 9084 | grep LISTEN | echo $? # but so does this
```

The problem as I interpret from the above is it's simply telling me my syntax is correct, but not really testing if that port is really listening

because when I do `netstat -an` I get the following output,which clearly shows only `9083` is listening but not `9084`

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established) Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local  Address           Foreign Address         State tcp       0      0 
 0.0.0.0:9083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN tcp    0      0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Though answering an old question, for future googlers, the following worked for me:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD netstat -an | grep 9083 > /dev/null; if [ 0 != $? ]; then exit 1; fi;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `/dev/tcp`

Like this :

`printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9083`

For more information, you can check this : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html#DEVTCP

Comment: This is nice, because curl, wget, netstat, all these may not be installed.

Answer (score 10):

The shorter version of it:

```
netstat -ltn | grep -c 9083
```

**Used options:**

[netstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat):

- `-l` - display listening server sockets
- `-t` - display TCP sockets only
- `-n` - don't resolve names

[grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

- `-c` - returns a number of founded lines, but it also gives a useful exit code; 0 if found, 1 if not found

Answer (score 3):

Piotr Perzynas answer is quite good, but it will also return 0 if there‘s a port like 19083 because it finds the substring 9083 in that line.
a better check would be:

```sh
netstat -ltn | grep -c ":9083"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I really loved Wassim Dhif answer. Mostly because it does not depend on netstat.
Netstat was obsolete before the question was asked.

From [netstat's manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat):

> **Note**
> This program is obsolete. Replacement for netstat is ss. Replacement for netstat -r is ip route. Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link. Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.

And you need netstat (or ss) installed in the container. You only want to check if a port is open. Wassim Dhif's answer just needs bash (and yes, not every image has it). In my experience, you usually want the image as light as possible.

In my compose I used it as follows:

```
healthcheck:
  test: "bash -c 'printf \"GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n\" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080; exit $?;'"
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 30s
```

Note that the string test is equivalent to specifying CMD-SHELL followed by that string (from the [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `nc`, `netstat` etc, you can simply use bash:

```
service:
    build: ./service
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: bash -c "exec 6<> /dev/tcp/localhost/80"
```